# Is it possible for Wordpress to know the UTM_SOURCE of a user registration?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I'm trying to figure out if I could somehow include the google analytics source of a WordPress users registration in the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You could track the utm parameter on the landingpage and persist it (e.g. via a cookie), but that would work only with campaign links.

It would be more promising (also more work, though) to pass a unique identifier to Google Analytics as session-scoped custom dimension and store the same identifier in the database. Then run a script on the next day (you have a 24 hour delay in processing time until the data is ready) and pull the utm sources for the identifiers, and insert them into the database.